# Macbook Air can't ping localhost

Tags: macbook, ping, localhost

I am having an issue with my Macbook Air, it cannot be pinged. I tried to ping it's IP from another computer, and the connection timed out. However, the Macbook Air **can** ping that computer. Although typing `ping 127.0.0.1` from the Macbook Air also results in timeouts.

Some things to note:
 - Macbook Air Mid 2011, OS X El Capital 10.11.6 with Bootcamp
 - Firewall is completely turned off
 - Remote Login is turned on
 - Stealth Mode is turned off
 - `/etc/hosts` is properly encoded (`ASCII English Text`)
 - I do not have Little Snitch or any antivirus software running.
 - Trying to `telnet localhost` results in connection refused
 - I tried all options on both my work network, as well as home network, with the same results on both networks.

I'm really at a loss at this point, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check if loopback interface is up, then check if the loopback has the proper ip/mask. firewall and REALLY weird routing tables could cause this too. (I'm no mac expert)

Comment: @behrooz How can I check that? I too am no mac expert, haha.

Comment: @behrooz I ran `ifconfig`, and the loopback interface seems to be up. `lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16834`

Comment: Update: I restarted the MacBook in safe mode, and I am able to ping localhost now. Does this imply there is some sort of startup software that is preventing incoming requests?

Comment: Update 2: I there was a folder in /Library/StartupItems, called `cma`, and looking at the files within it, it seemed to be related to MacAfee. I deleted that folder, restarted in Normal Mode (instead of safe mode), but I still can't ping localhost. I can only ping in safe mode... very strange

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out the problem, it was McAfee. I navigated to `/Library/McAfee/uninstall.sh`, typed `sudo ./uninstall.sh`. After it was uninstalled, I restarted and I can ping myself now, as well as ping the mac from other computers.